# Does my addOnGlobalLayoutListener working in a background

Tags: java, android

I cant understand where is my addOnGlobalLayoutListener running.

I have a method that have a callback? on a layout inflating(as I understand)

```
private void getSymbolsInRowCount(float textSize, BaseActivity activity){
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.page_fragment,null);
        ((BookView)activity.view).layout.addView(view);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //size = ((TextView) view).getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
         view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    () -> {
                            Log.e("why", ((TextView) view).getLayout().getLineEnd(0) + 1 + "");
                            symbolsInRowCount = ((TextView) view).getLayout().getLineEnd(0) + 1;
                    });
    }
```

And it's strange what when I create new thread and invoke `sleep()`, callback is never completed. Only after `sleep` passed.

```
public List<String> getPages(String text){
        List<String> pageList=new ArrayList<>();
        String divider = " ";

        Thread thread;

        new Thread(()-> {
            Log.e("why", "2");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
            return null;
        }
```

I invoke them consequentially, and can't understand where i'm wrong.

```
public PageDivider(BaseActivity activity, float textSize,String text){
        this.activity=activity;
        getSymbolsInRowCount(textSize,activity);
        rowsCount=getRowsCount(true,true,true);
        List<String> list=getPages(text);
    }
```

Help me please, how can I make callback in a separate thread?

Comment: `Callback method to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes`[OnGlobalLayoutListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)

Comment: Ok, but why it isn't invokes in my case? After all, I invoke `sleep()` not in the UI Thread, isn't it?

Comment: try setting view's visibility after you set listener

Comment: Nah, it wont helps, problem is what my callback invokes but only after a `sleep()`, and doesn't matter how long `sleep` is.